# How I can get the server error response, using selenium webdriver with java code?

Tags: java, http, selenium-webdriver, get, request

I make some tests using selenium web-driver with java code.
The test includes filling form.
After click on "send", if something was wrong with one of the fields, I will get an error message back from the server.
How did I handle with this message?

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLkv5.png)

Comment: It is not possible to do it with selenium (it is against Selenium idea of testing user interface - e2e testing). The only possible way is use proxy: 1. run proxy, 2. start selenium browser using proxy, 3. capture proxy traffic, 4. analyze traffic

Comment: Is the error message displayed in browser?

Comment: Can you provide some more information as below : 1. Are the error messages coupled with the respective fields/elements ? 2. Are the error messages in the form of Alerts? 3. Can you provide some snapshot? 4. Provide the HTML DOM.